# JS script - if statement ignores jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build my own slider for a webpage, because I don't wanna use the Bootstrap one.
However now I'm facing an issue with if statement ignoring my jQuery animation.

```
// SLIDER

$(".dot").click(function(){
  let currentId = ($(".dot-active").attr("id")[$(".dot-active").attr("id").length - 1]);
  let nextId = event.target.id[(event.target.id).length - 1];

  $(".dot-active").removeClass("dot-active");
  $("#" + event.target.id).addClass("dot-active");

  if(Number(currentId) < Number(nextId)){
    $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 350);
  } else {
    $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 350);
  };
  $("#slide" + currentId).addClass("slide-inactive");
  $("#slide" + currentId).removeClass("slide-active");

  if(Number(currentId) < Number(nextId)){
    $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 350);
  } else {
    $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 350);
  };
  $("#slide" + nextId).removeClass("slide-inactive");
  $("#slide" + nextId).addClass("slide-active");
});
```

I tried to put alerts into the if statement and it worked, so it just doesn't recognize the jQuery line of code probably. Also, without the if statement the animations work good. Does anybody know why, please?

Also one additional question:
when I run this code without the if statement (with just one direction of slide) on the first click event the first animation doesn't work, after that every animation works properly, does anybody know why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had bugs there, my bad.
Fixed it here

```
// SLIDER

$(".dot").click(function(){
  let currentId = ($(".dot-active").attr("id")[$(".dot-active").attr("id").length - 1]);
  let nextId = event.target.id[(event.target.id).length - 1];

  $(".dot-active").removeClass("dot-active");
  $("#" + event.target.id).addClass("dot-active");

  if(Number(currentId) < Number(nextId)){
  $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 350);
  } else {
    $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 350);
  };
  $("#slide" + currentId).addClass("slide-inactive");
  $("#slide" + currentId).removeClass("slide-active");

  if(Number(currentId) < Number(nextId)){
  $("#slide" + nextId).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 350);
  } else {
    $("#slide" + nextId).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 350);
  };
  $("#slide" + nextId).removeClass("slide-inactive");
  $("#slide" + nextId).addClass("slide-active");
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Well, the bugs I had there were following:
1) using wrong variable in the last part of code, where everything should have been related to nextId but I had the currentId pasted there

2) using .hide function in last part of code instead of .show function

Will definitely come 2 days later to check the answer